# In this circuit why am I getting a voltage of 3,99V when the voltage source is only 2V?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

In the circuit below I have to calculate the values for the voltmeter and the ammeter, in the ammeter the result I got was -0.057 A which is the correct value, but in the voltmeter I can not seem to figure out how to calculate it.

[image: circuit]

Comment: Work out the voltage on each resistive divider separately. That gives you the voltages at each terminal of the voltmeter.

Comment: @BrianDrummond just one more thing, I remade the circuit like in the link.  The value I got was 3,99V does that mean that the value of the voltmeter is the sum of the voltages in each group of resistors in series? https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/22752194_1925733324109820_1901300590_n.jpg?oh=c529fd516f7631feb62feac75e251897&oe=59EE415E

Comment: If you got 3.99V via a passive network from a 2V source then you went wrong somewhere.

Comment: but that is the value in the solution

Comment: @BrianDrummond But if the solution is wrong what is the correct value? Thank you

Comment: @RodrigoPina We’re not here to do your homework. You should at least explain how you got that answer so we can hint you where your mistake is.

Comment: Hint: a voltmeter measures the *potential difference* between two points.

Comment: @user2233709 First I calculated the current which gave -0.057A, then I remade the circuit like in the link, and used nodal analysis to calculate Ix and using Ix I calculated the voltage drop in each group of resistors in series then I added those two values and got 3.99V which is the value in the solution. https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/22752194_1925733324109820_1901300590_n.jpg?oh=c529fd516f7631feb62feac75e251897&oe=59EE415E

Comment: Add the photo into your question and show the rest of your calculations. Hint number 2: do you know how to calculate the voltage in a two-resistor voltage divider?

Comment: @Transistor isnt it Vx=V*R1/(R1+R2)?

Comment: Correct. Now you have two voltage dividers. No need to work out the currents - just work out the voltages for the voltmeter probes.

Comment: @Transistor so is it Vx= 2 * 60/(10+60) and Vy= 2*20/(20+50) and the value at the voltmeter is Vx+Vy?

Comment: Close. Read my first comment. You can post this as an answer to your own question and accept it (when you get it right).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67433/discussion-between-rodrigo-pina-and-transistor).